# Is there terminology of the form "$n$-something form" that generalizes quadratic form and cubic forms?

Tags: polynomials, terminology

By definition, a quadratic form is a [homogeneous polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial) of degree $2$, and a cubic form is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $3$. Is there accepted terminology, like $n$-ic form, $n$-atic form, etc. to mean "homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$"? I'm not arguing that we actually *need* this terminology, I just want to know if its out there.

Comment: Yeah, I’ve heard the expression “$n$-ic form”. They do indeed occur.

Comment: While quadric or sextic sound right, I think in general you would just say $n$-form.